# Notify Observers doesn't take changes with compute or subscribe

Tags: knockout.js

I need set an observable value after another has change value. Example:

I have this:

```
Billing.FinishBillViewModel = function () {

    this.billingId = ko.observable();
    this.billingIva = ko.observable(0);
    this.billingSubTotal = ko.observable(0);

    this.billingTotal = ko.observable(0);
    this.billingReceivedValue = ko.observable(0);
    this.billingReturnedValue = ko.observable(0);
    this.billingCode = ko.observable();
        };
```

And when `this.billingReceivedValue` set a value by keyboard, the arithmetic operation over `this.billingReturnedValue` must be this one:

```
this.billingReturnedValue(this.billingReceivedValue() - this.billingTotal())
```

I have tried compute and observable and I does not reflect the change of my observables ...

How I can do that?

Comment: Can you expand on what you've tried with a `computed`?  This is the sort of thing they're ideal for

Comment: Hi, using compute I tryed this and does not work: 

**`
        this.billingReturnedValue = ko.computed(function () {
            return this.billingReceivedValue() * this.billingTotal();
        }, this);`**

Comment: That looks right.  Perhaps you need to edit in some more context to your question - how is this model being used etc, that computed looks fine

Comment: Note that you can edit your question to add details or improve it. If substantial it will also bump your question.

Comment: Fixed ... The trouble was that in the binding I was making this: 'data-binding:"text: [Property]" ... ' and the correct way is: 'data-binding:"value: [Property]" ... ' ... Tnks ... I will investigate diferences between text and value bindings .... –